# Ruby gem for Salesforce Soap Api

Tags: ruby, soap, rubygems, salesforce

There are couple of gems for Salesforce Rest Api and Bulk Api. Is there any gem for Salesforce SOAP Api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of try outs, I settled for `Savon Gem`.

Answer (score 0):

https://rubygems.org/gems/databasedotcom

This Gem provides ActiveRecord-like access to Salesforce objects.  I've had good luck
with it.  It abstracts the SOAP/REST protocol.